# Doctrine cascade "remove" doesn't delete rows after emptying ManyToOne owner's collection

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I have the following two entities:

```php
/** @Entity @Table(name="invoice") */
class Invoice {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;
    ...
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="InvoiceRow", mappedBy="invoice", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true) */
    protected $rows = null;
    ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->rows = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...

    public function getRows() {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public function addRow($row) {
        $this->rows[] = $row;
        $row->setInvoice($this);
    }

    public function emptyRows() {
        $this->rows = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

```php
/** @Entity @Table(name="invoice_row") */
class InvoiceRow {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;
    ...
    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="rows") */
    protected $invoice;
    ...
    
    public function getInvoice() {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    public function setInvoice($invoice) {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
    }
}
```

So, an instance of `Invoice` can have many instances of `InvoiceRow` associated.
After reflecting the entities structure on the DB, I have the field `invoice_id` in table `invoice_row` which correctly refers to the `id` of the associated record of table `invoice`.

As every row of an invoice can be added, deleted or modified, every time I save an invoice, I want to delete all the associated records of `InvoiceRow` and recreate the records as they are received from the frontend.

This is the code:

```php
public static function saveInvoice($invoiceData, $invoiceRows) {
    $em = getEntityManager();

    $dbInvoice = null;
    if ($invoiceData->id) {
        // if is an exsisting invoice, i get it from the DB, so Doctrine will execute an update instead of an insert
        $dbInvoice = $em->find(Invoice::class, $invoiceData->id);
    }

    $dbInvoice->emptyRows(); // deleting all the rows from the entity Invoice

    // adding all the rows, as they were received from the frontend
    foreach ($invoiceRows as $invoiceRow) {
        $dbInvoiceRow = self::getDbInvoiceRow($invoiceRow) // map frontend object into the Doctrine entity InvoiceRow
        $dbInvoice->addRiga($dbInvoiceRow);
    }

    $em->persist($dbInvoice);
    $em->flush();
}
```

The problem is that, in the end, instead of having only the rows received from the frontend, I still have all the old rows, as no rows has been deleted.

For example:
original data in `invoice_row` table:

```sql
| id | invoice_id | code | description |
| -- | ---------- | ---- | ----------- |
| 1  | 12         | 010  | product 01  |
| 2  | 12         | 008  | product 02  |
```

rows received from the frontend:

```sql
| code | description |
| ---- | ----------- |
| 010  | product 01  |
| 012  | product 03  |
```

expected content of invoice_row table:

```sql
| id | invoice_id | code | description |
| -- | ---------- | ---- | ----------- |
| 1  | 12         | 010  | product 01  |
| 3  | 12         | 012  | product 03  |
```

real content after the persist

```sql
| id | invoice_id | code | description |
| -- | ---------- | ---- | ----------- |
| 1  | 12         | 010  | product 01  | -> old row
| 2  | 12         | 008  | product 02  | -> old row
| 3  | 12         | 010  | product 01  |
| 4  | 12         | 012  | product 03  |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the point. I'm disappointed I couldn't achieve that through cascade remove or other annotations, but I had to write more code.
Here is how I figured it out:

- I added the following method to the class `Invoice`

```php
public function deleteRows() {
    foreach ($this->rows as $row) {
        $this->rows->removeElement($row);
    }
    $this->rows = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

and I changed the invoice save procedure as follows:

```php
public static function saveInvoice($invoiceData, $invoiceRows) {
    $em = getEntityManager();

    $dbInvoice = null;
    if ($invoiceData->id) {
        // if is an existing invoice, i get it from the DB, so Doctrine will execute an update instead of an insert
        $dbInvoice = $em->find(Invoice::class, $invoiceData->id);
    }

    $dbInvoice->deleteRows(); // deleting all the rows from the entity Invoice

    // adding all the rows, as they were received from the frontend
    foreach ($invoiceRows as $invoiceRow) {
        $dbInvoiceRow = self::getDbInvoiceRow($invoiceRow) // map frontend object into the Doctrine entity InvoiceRow
        $dbInvoice->addRow($dbInvoiceRow);
    }

    $em->persist($dbInvoice);
    $em->flush();
}
```

At the end, so, to make it easier, the only way I could figure it out was to explicitly call the `removeElement`, but including that as a function in the `Invoice` class made it more consistent with the entity itself.

I  hope this will help future readers.